# Upload custom font files

Tags: 8, css-js-aggregation

I've been given a directory full of font files (woff2, svg, ttf file types). Is there a way to get these fonts to load when a page is rendered in Drupal? Is there a specific directory I have to put them in or a module that handles custom fonts?

I took a look at the contrib [fontyourface](https://www.drupal.org/project/fontyourface) module, but it seems to require using external providers instead of being able to upload your own font files.

Comment: CSS has a method to load font files, and as fonts belong to the theming layer, it is ok that they are loaded as the style sheets are loaded. Font are always kinda clunky in my experience...

Comment: This also works well with SASS/LESS workflows, and the fonts will never be called if the style sheets are not loaded.

Comment: Ship it with the theme, no module needed. Have CSS load them.

Answer (score 8):

Do you have a custom theme? If so, you can implement it like this:

Place your fonts in your custom theme, following something similar to this folder structure:

```
themes
  custom
    my_custom_theme
      fonts
        my_font.woff2
        my_font.ttf
        my_font.svg
```

And then in your CSS file (it might be in `themes/custom/my_custom_theme/css/style.css` for example) add the following:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "my_font;
  src: url('/fonts/my_font.woff');
  src: url('/fonts/my_font.ttf');
  src: url('/fonts/my_font.svg');
}
```

Comment: Please explain in detail.

Comment: Do you not need the format section? ```url('../fonts/my_font.tff') format('tff');```